# How do I increase the speed of my microprocessor?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, microprocessors

This is my PC's specification:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz   2.00 GHz
Installed RAM   4.00 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

How do I increase processor speed to run Android Studio and the Android Emulator faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this but this might cost you a little bit in order to run your Android Studio faster than before.

The solution is

1. You have to get yourself an SSD
2. Upgrade your RAM to 8GB min

Upgrade these two components. You won't get this kind of issue again.

Comment: What if I only get an SSD without upgrading the RAM would it change anything??

Comment: Can I also do it vice versa??

Comment: What kind of hard drive are you using right now?

Comment: Answer: you will get some benefit in each case.  Just not as much as if you upgraded both.  (And we can't quantify it for you ...)