# How can I speed up my pc for Android development ft. Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

Now you can easily notice I am new on app development path when I am setting up Android studio for Android development I find that my pc need specific requirements (Hardware) to start

But I have desktop that
CPU : Core 2Duo
RAM : 4 GB
HDD : 500 GB

It's been week when I just run some basic apps but it's very headache to do it for basics app because my android studio every minute got hang and start lagging I can't open chrome there full of warehouse of my problems related to pc because of android studio

Anyone know any hacks or by tips for me you can feel free for it.

Comment: Please check this link [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407228/how-do-i-increase-the-speed-of-my-microprocessor/71407376?noredirect=1#comment126227903_71407376) this might solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: There is good news after I posted this question I upgraded my PC to i5 3rd gen with 8 GB ram plus 120 GB SSD. And now i am grinding on my journey.

Answer (score 1):

The only hacks I can think of are:

- Make sure you are not using a remote mounted file system or "share" for either your Android Studio + Java installation or your AS workspace.
- Shutoff (quit) all other applications that are using significant amounts of RAM; e.g. your web browsers, your email tool, Slack, Zoom, etc.
- If you are using Windows, switch to Linux.

---

Better idea: get a better development machine.  I think that the RAM is most important, because it sounds like your machine is thrashing.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it bluntly: those specs are simply not enough to do any serious modern development. If you *could* replacing the HDD with an SSD (even a small, cheap one) would be the highest priority and more memory is second. A better CPU would obviously help, but it's a luxury, the other two items are more important.

Assuming that's not an option, you can do either of those two things:

- don't use an IDE (or at least a more light-weight one, such as VS Code) and build your software from the command line. This will be more painful (especially when you're just starting) and even then the resource requirements of the build will be non-trivial.
- Make sure to do as little as possible on your local machine. If you have a decent internet connection, then you might be better off developing on a free remote cloud computer and use something like [Projector](https://lp.jetbrains.com/projector/) to show the UI in the browser. I've found [this repo with instructions on how to use it with Android Studio](https://github.com/joaquim-verges/ProjectorAndroidStudio), which seems useful, but I've not verified that it works.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem unfair but Android Studio is not really suitable to run in a lower end device. It used to lag/hang in my device with Core i7 and 8GB Ram. The best thing you can do is to use an SSD instead of HDD. SSDs with smaller memory are often cheap and this alone can somewhat lessen your problems with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should  change your HDD to 240 GB SSD and it will works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).